# Javascript populates input, but not span?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 dropdown menu to get data from database threw ajax and json/php.
The option i make will then populate some input fileds for editing the database.

I use (This field get´s populated ok):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valt_element_id" id="valt_element_id" placeholder="Objekt ID" />
```

But on some field i just want to show the data, not to be edited.
I figured to use:

```
<span id="valt_element_id"></span>
```

But this span code won´t work!
Why?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var valtObjektElement = $('#valj_objekt_element');
$('#valj_objekt_element').select2({

    ajax: {
    url: "valj_objekt_element.php",
    dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
            q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data };
        }
    } // Ajax Call
}); // Select2

// Start Change
$(valtObjektElement).change(function() {

    var ElementId = $(valtObjektElement).select2('data').id;
    var ObjektNummer = $(valtObjektElement).select2('data').text;

    $('#valt_element_id').val(ElementId);
    $('#valt_objekt_nummer').val(ObjektNummer);

}); //Change
}); //Domument Ready
```

Comment: Please show your javascript.

Comment: You seem to use an id multiple times which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `value` attribute for `span`. You should either use `text` or `html`.

Replace

```
$('#valt_element_id').val(ElementId);
```

with

```
$('#valt_element_id').text(ElementId);
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked fine! I will update my knowledge on attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("valt_element_id").innerHTML = ElementId;
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('#valt_element_id').html(ElementId);
```

Comment: Thank you. Where can i read about .val .text & .html attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned:

`But on some field i just want to show the data, not to be edited` . Why not use `readonly` attribute in `input` rather than replacing it with a `span` ?

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and see what i like the most =)